# PayPal 3rd party permission revoke notification

Tags: authentication, paypal, permissions, notifications

If granted permission is revoked from PayPal UI there is no notification is sent to granted account. Does anyone know anything about notifications that is sent when permissions are revoked?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no specific notification that gets sent with this happens.  Of course, the next time your app makes a call for the account that revoked the permissions you would get an error that you don't have permissions to make the call, so you could update your system any time it sees that error, and that would be your notification.